# How to change polymer 1.0 paper-button color dynamically from an array of colors?

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I have an array buttonColors, which has set of colors in the hex format.
Now I want to display set of paper-button each with the color present in the buttonColors Array. How to achieve it in polymer 1.0?

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{buttonColors}}">
      <paper-button style="background-color:{{item}}" >
                  <b>click me</b>
      </paper-button>
</template>
```

The above snippet does not seem to work. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried using javascript to create a bunch of buttons using the colors you have in your array?

Comment: I used javascript to create the array of colors, now since dom-repeat provides us with the facility to iterate an array, I should be able to add style property to paper-button. But I dont find the way.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you can. If you follow [this link](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html) and programmatically made different styles you could apply these styles to your buttons by specifying which style to use for each button.

Comment: 1.0 doesn't support expressions in `{{}}` bindings. You'll need to make it a computed property: `style="{{_computeStyle(item)}}"`. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#data-binding

Comment: do you mean I need to call a computeStyle function? can you post a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function and call it in following way

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{buttonColors}}">
      <paper-button style="{{computeStyle(item)}}" >
                  <b>click me</b>
      </paper-button>
</template>

<script>
computedStyle:function(cl)
{
 var s= "background-color:"+cl;
  return s;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

ebidel's comment is excellent as always. *(He is one of the Google geniuses responsible building Polymer BTW)*

> *1.0 doesn't support expressions in* `{{}}` *bindings. You'll need to make it a computed property:* `style="{{_computeStyle(item)}}"` ... [Documentation](http://polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#data-binding)

Below, I have written out some example code for you to follow.

---

#### Example Code

```
<dom-module id="x-element">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{buttonColors}}">
    <paper-button style$="{{_computeStyle}}"> <b>click me</b> </paper-button>
  </template> ...
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: "x-element",
        properties: {
          value: {
            type: Number,
            notify: true
          }
        },
        _computeStyle: function(item) {
          // Compute style here
          return "background-color:red";
        }
      });
    })()
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: @ebidel and Mowzer -
I've got this working on initial load of the element.  But I have a problem - it seems that I can't get my function, like "computeStyle" to evaluate, after changing the items array.  Any thoughts on how I can trigger the computed property to re-compute, when the items array changes??  Thanks.